# Add a transform (rotateZ) & left animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After opening the envelope flap, the pink paper in the JSFiddle supposed to rotate & move to the left. How can I add another animation (transform rotateZ & left) in the JQuery? (You can add CSS, too.)

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.alpha').removeClass('nodelta').addClass('delta');
    $('.alpha.delta').click(
            function () {
                $(this).find('.beta').addClass('etha');
            }
    );
});
```

[Here's the link to my JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/MaryWilliameTaraneeChristine/xhkuwm72/)

Answer (score 1):

Although your Question is not clear You can use add css to etha class so it rollover the changes with `transition` css property i.e:

```
.etha{
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) !important;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make change to your code like below, That's it...

```
$(function () {
    $('.alpha').removeClass('nodelta').addClass('delta');
    $('.alpha.delta').click(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.beta').addClass('etha');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.fbl').css({"transform":"rotateZ(90deg)","left":"0"});
            },300);
        }
    );
});
```